# Manipulating binding variables in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, binding

Suppose I have a string that's binding:

```
@Binding var string: String
```

But, I want to manipulate that string, and then pass it to a child view.

```
struct ViewOne: View {
    @State var string: String = "Hello"
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewTwo(string: string + " World") // this is invalid, as ViewTwo requires Binding<String>
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @Binding var string: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
    }
}
```

How should I go about manipulating that string, such that it will update the UI when the state changes? Let's assume that I want to re-use `ViewTwo` for different components, and so I would want to manipulate the string before it is passed to the view.

A computed variable doesn't work, as it isn't `Binding`

```
private var fixedString: String {
    return string + " World"
}
```

And I don't want to create a binding variable, because the `setter` makes no sense in this context

```
private var fixedString: Binding<String> {
    Binding<String> (
        get: {
            string + " World"
        }, set: {
            // this function doesn't make sense here - how would it update the original variable?
        }
    )
}
```

Am I just using `@State` and `@Binding` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `@Binding` inside `ViewTwo`:

```
struct ViewTwo: View {
    var string: String /// no need for the `@Binding`!
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI *will* update `ViewTwo` even if you don't have the `@Binding` (it basically re-renders the entire `body` whenever a `@State` or `@Published` var gets changed).

You only need Bindings when you need to update/set the original `@State` or `@Published` property. In that case you'd add something like the `var fixedString: Binding<String>` in your question.